# Look vs. looks in specific example

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

I know these two sentences are correct, but I can't figure out why! Can someone please educate me?

1. The cake looks delicious.
2. The decorations make the cake look delicious.

Why isn't the singular *cake* combined with the plural *looks* in both examples?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Looks' isn't plural, the s at the end means that it is conjugated for the third person singular.

In the second sentence, look is an infinitive. This is because it doesn't have a subject, 'the cake' is the object of the verb 'make'. This is clearer if you use pronouns, for instance, 'I saw **him**(object) **run**(infinitive) away.

Comment: Also, the conjugated verb in the second sentence is "make", which is third person _plural_ to match "The decorations".